# Concatenate Raphaël Sets

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg, raphael, concatenation

With the [Raphaël library](http://raphaeljs.com/), you can create sets, which are array-like objects that hold Raphaël elements and can implicitly loop over those elements when an element method is called. The issue is that although the sets are array-*like*, not all of the functions in the `Array` prototype are available for Raphaël sets, including `Array.concat()`. How do I concatenate two Raphaël sets and into a new one? I don't want to modify either of the original sets.

Comment: You knew the answer before you asked...

Comment: Well, actually, I thought of the question and began typing it. Then, I figured out the answer. However, I had already typed the question, so I just answered it.

Comment: Anyways, if this works, someone might benefit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured out a way. The secret is that a Raphaël set has an undocumented property called `items`, which is a normal array of the Raphaël elements that the set holds.

A Raphaël set does have something similar to the `Array.splice()` method, which is used to remove and insert elements from and into arrays. The syntax of `Array.splice()` is `anArray.splice(startingIndex, numberOfItemsToRemove, itemToInsert[, anotherItemToInsert...])`. The function creates an empty set and them simply `splice`s the items from the two existing sets into the new set. In this case, both `startingIndex` and `numberOfItemsToRemove` should be `0` because a new set has a `length` of `0`, which means that the only index is `0` and that you couldn't possibly remove more than `0` elements.

The function below makes use of JavaScript's `function.apply()` method on `splice()` (as in `splice.apply()`). `apply()` takes two arguments: a value that gets assigned to the `this` keyword inside the function and an array that becomes the function's arguments. We can create an array to pass to `apply()` as the arguments to `splice()`. The first two items in this array are `startingIndex` and `numberOfItemsToRemove`, so they will both be set to `0`. All of the subsequent arguments are items to be inserted into the new set. We can initialize this array with `[0, 0]`, which is a real array, which **does** have the `concat()` method. All that we have to do now is `concat()` each set's elements, which we can get from the `item` property of the set, onto the end of `[0, 0]`, creating an array of arguments that will be passed to the `splice()` method of the new, empty set.

```
function concatSets(paper, setA, setB){
    var newSet = paper.set(); // Creates a new, empty set
    newSet.splice.apply(newSet, [0, 0].concat(setA.items, setB.items));
    return newSet;
}
```

The function below can concatenate as many sets as you need; just pass in an array of sets as the second argument and the paper object as the first. If `arrayOfSets.length == 1`, then the function simply creates a copy of the set.

```
function concatManySets(paper, arrayOfSets){
    var i, newSet, argsToPass;
    argsToPass = [0, 0]; // The first two parameters of a normal call to Array.splice()
    newSet = paper.set(); // Creates a new, empty set
    for(i = 0; i < arrayOfSets.length; i++){
        argsToPass = argsToPass.concat(arrayOfSets[i].items);
    }
    newSet.splice.apply(newSet, argsToPass);
    return newSet;
}
```